# Access parent scope subject in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

How can i access the parent scope's subject when defining the current scope's subject in RSpec (refining the subject)?

Example code:

```
describe MyModule.method(:some_method) do

  context "when called with a String" do
    let(:string) { "Hey there!" }

    # I want to refine the subject using the parent scope's subject - common case
    # is applying a subject method. Something like:
    subject { super.subject.call string }

    # Use subject...

  end # when called with a String

end # MyModule.some_method
```

Comment: You are nearly there: `subject { super() }` is ok.

Comment: @mudasobwa really? I'll go back and try again, but I swear I had `super.call` in there (should be same as `super().call`) and it wasn't working...

Comment: @mudasobwa huh, the `super().call` works (`super.call` doesn't)... weird... I guess I don't totally understand `super`, I thought it was a method call? Anyways, much thanks!

Comment: OK, I see... bare `super` uses the "implicit passing of arguments" funky-ness, and it doesn't know what to do in that case, but `super()` explicitly tells it no args and it's cool with that.

Comment: Exactly. I have been there (not in `rspec`, but anyway) and since then I always pass parameters in calls to `super` explicitly. Honestly, I hate magic :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really a fan of the implicit `super` args... especially since it obviously breaks down in some cases (think this involves use of `def_method`). I probably could have figured it out if I had paid closer attention to the error message, but I guess I'm pretty accustomed to not being able to figure out what the hell RSpec is actually doing without significant effort.

Answer (score 2):

OK, credit to @mudasobwa from the comments above, here's the solution:

You need to call `super()` with *explicitly no arguments* - `super` alone won't work, because it tries to use Ruby's implicit passing of arguments and fails.

Corrected example:

```
describe MyModule.method(:some_method) do

  context "when called with a String" do
    let(:string) { "Hey there!" }

    # Note the explicit `()`:
    subject { super().call string }

    # Use subject...

  end # when called with a String

end # MyModule.some_method
```

Answer (score 0):

you can name your subject:

```
context do 
  subject(:my_thing) { described_class.new }

  context '#do_stuff'
    subject { my_thing.do_stuff }

    it { expect(subject).to ... } # or
    it { is_expected.to ... }
  end
end
```

Comment: [Docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-6/docs/metadata/described-class) seems to imply `described_class` only applies if outer-most subject is a class (in this case it's a method). Anyways, I think I was wanting to use `subject` to make shared examples easier without passing parameters.